# Using an Array[10] and incrementing it with a While loop using modulo 10 to Pair User inputs together

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int number;
    int digits;
    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> number;
    int counter[10] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    while (number != 0) {
        digits = number % 10;
        counter[digits] = counter[digits] + 1;
        number = number / 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        if (counter[i] != 0) {
            cout << i << ": " << counter[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
    system("pause");
}
```

I'm having an issue with my code that when I run it and enter a Number nothing really happens. It is supposed to run something like 1234556789 and the output should look like
1 : 9
2 : 8
3 : 7
4 : 6
5 : 5

I know sometimes if there isn't a system pause this happens where it runs part of the code and just ends, but I'm not sure whats wrong here.

Comment: What is the question? Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.

Comment: Perhaps you need to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?

Comment: `int counter[10] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };` can be shortened to `int counter[10] = { 0 };`. Also, putting `system("pause")` after `return 0` makes it pointless.

Comment: I think if you use a debugger to step through your code, the problem will be very obvious to you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude In all honesty that blog doesn't do a single thing to teach newcomers how to debug their programs. If the OP doesn't know what breakpoints  and stepping through the code are then there is very little in that blog for them. The post seems to be tailored to established developers.

Comment: You don't even need a debugger. You can just `cout` the contents of `digits` and `counter[digits]` every iteration. That made the problem obvious to me.

Comment: @Ron It have some very good advice for enabling warnings (a good compiler would warn about the useless statements after the `return` for example), [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), minimizing the stuff you do, testing and more. Using a debugger is very late in that post and is *also* a good advice. And learning all these techniques (including using a debugger) is a *must* for anyone who wants to learn programming, even if only for a hobby. Also, part of learning programming is the ability to do research yourself. Like *learning* to use debuggers.

Comment: @Ron: It gives them terms they can research using their favourite search engine. Are we really here to do _all_ the work for them from scratch?

Comment: To be honest I had never used a debugger before because at my school they make you take the basics of diffrent languages, and when I learned some C with a diffrent teacher, she told me not to use it. So, I never have until now. Thanks for the advice. I'm not sure why she said not to use it.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Valid points.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int number;
    int digits;
    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> number;
    int counter[10]={0},a=0;
    while (number != 0) {
        digits = number % 10;
        counter[a] = digits;     //made changes to this line
        number = number / 10;
        ++a;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++) {
        if (counter[i] != 0) {
            cout << i << ": " << counter[i] << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are doing right now is printing how many digits there are of each number 0-9 in the number. If you want to pair elements together, then you can use `std::vector` and iterators. The number of digits in your input can be either even or odd and you would have to account for both cases.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long int number;
    cout << "Enter Number: ";
    cin >> number;
    vector<int> digits;

    if (number == 0)
    {
        digits.push_back(number);
    }
    while (number != 0)
    {
        digits.push_back(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }

    auto it_begin = digits.begin();
    auto it_end = digits.end() - 1;

    if (digits.size() % 2 == 1)
    {
        for (; it_end != it_begin; ++it_begin, --it_end)
        {
            cout << *it_end << ": " << *it_begin << endl;
        }

        cout << *it_end << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        for (; it_begin < it_end; ++it_begin, --it_end)
        {
            cout << *it_end << ": " << *it_begin << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

With number = 1234556789, the output is:

```
1: 9
2: 8
3: 7
4: 6
5: 5
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want first 10 no. Only use this code

include using namespace std;int main() {long int number;cout << "Enter Number: ";cin >> number;for (int i = 1; i<=10; i++) {cout << i << ": "<